# From Haskell, how to call a sqlite query plan?

Tags: sqlite, haskell

In sqlite, I can run a command like:

```
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN SELECT employee FROM employees WHERE manager = 'joe'
```

and get something like:

```
QUERY PLAN
`--SEARCH employees USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_employees_1 (manager=?)
```

which tells me how the primary key index is being used to perform that query. (primary key is composite in this case)

In Haskell's `sqlite-simple` library, I am familiar with the `query` and `query_` functions,

```
query :: (ToRow q, FromRow r) => Connection -> Query -> q -> IO [r]
query_ :: FromRow r => Connection -> Query -> IO [r]
```

Which could run a string-defined query, but their return type of `FromRow r => [r]` precludes them from being able to compile a Query Plan, for which the return type would have to be something like another string. When I try to compile one I get this error:

> No instance for (FromRow Char) arising from a use of ‘query_’

There are some other variations on `query` and `query_` in Database.SQLite.Simple, but I do not see one which looks like it could return a string, or otherwise, the result of a query plan request.

Is there any way to run an sqlite query plan from Haskell?

Comment: I bet it returns one string per row, with one or more rows. Try using a list of strings as the return type.

Comment: From [the docs](https://sqlite.org/lang_explain.html): *The output from EXPLAIN and EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN is intended for interactive analysis and troubleshooting only. The details of the output format are subject to change from one release of SQLite to the next. Applications should not use EXPLAIN or EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN since their exact behavior is variable and only partially documented.*